# Minikube service not working on windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am using minikube 1.16.0 on windows 10 with kubernetes v 1.19.0 .I can see the services and  deployment on minikube dashboard and as well by running `minikube service list` and when running `minikube service servicetwo` it opens a link in the browser but connection refused is showing on browser.any help would be really appreciated

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: servicetwo
      labels:
        name: servicetwo
      
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:               
        matchLabels:
          name: servicetwo     
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            name: servicetwo
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: servicetwo
            image: swapnadeepdas/servicetwo
            ports:
             - containerPort: 5000
    
            
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: servicetwo
      labels:
        name: servicetwo
     
    spec:
      ports:
        # the port that this service should serve on
      - port: 5000
        targetPort: 5000
        nodePort: 30003
      selector:
        name: servicetwo
      type: NodePort  
    ---
```

Comment: Are the pods up and running? Did your application work locally w/o minikube? Can you provide more info about app and any logs if available?

Comment: Yes pods are up and running ,and it worked without minikube and working on minikube on mac too